# first time running Flutter Project

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, gradle

I just installed (Android Studio 4.0.1) with (ProtonVPN) because I live in Syria
when i tried to run new Flutter application
it's give me this Error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 41
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

> Could not find method google() for arguments [] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8m 12s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

i run flutter doctor -v code and this the result:

```html
C:\Users\MSI>flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.329], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.20.4 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision fba99f6cf9 (2 weeks ago), 2020-09-14 15:32:52 -0700
    • Engine revision d1bc06f032
    • Dart version 2.9.2


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\MSI\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 49.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7547
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.49.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\MSI\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.14.1

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • SM G973N (mobile) • 127.0.0.1:62001 • android-x86 • Android 5.1.1 (API 22)

• No issues found!
```

my app\build.gradle

```html
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.test_app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}
```

my gradle-wrapper.properties

```html
#Fri Jun 23 08:50:38 CEST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip
```

my android\build.gradle

```html
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just delete the Android and ios folder from the flutter directory.

Remove invalid cache using an android studio.

Create the new android and ios directory using `flutter create .`
and make sure you have a good internet connection.

EDITED Answer :

Flutter had unstaged changes (since it uses git), so I needed to stash or reset it to be able to upgrade it.

Go to flutter's path and:

```
git add -A
git reset --hard
```

Alternatively, you can use --force to upgrade it anyway.

`flutter upgrade --force`

Comment: thanx Abhishek Ghaskata, when i did search in C:\src\flutter for Android and ios folder it give me a lot of Android and ios folders so delete all of them or delete Android and ios folder in my Project Location ? after that run 'flutter create .' in android studio terminal ?

Comment: Delete Android and iOS directory from project only.

Comment: i did everything you told me but still have the same Error!!

Comment: please update your flutter using `flutter upgrade` and try with new project.

Comment: i used (flutter upgrade) in terminal of Android Studio it's give me this Error{Your flutter checkout has local changes that would be erased by upgrading. If you want to keep these changes, it is recommended that you stash them via "git stash" or else
commit the changes to a local branch. If it is okay to remove local changes, then re-run this command with --force.}

Comment: Thanx dude so much your edited answer worked for me @Abhishek Ghaskata